# Unrest value in a 'foreach' loop

Tags: php, loops

I have an order like this

```
product quantity inventory
   1       5        50
   1       6        50
   7       2        150
   1       6        50
```

I am trying to loop in each product and *decrease* the *inventory*

Total inventory for product 1 is 50

**in loop**

```
product 1 the inventory become 45
product 1 the inventory becomes 39
product 7 the inventory becomes 148
product 1 the inventory becomes 44
```

Hers is the issue in the last loop the inventory has been rest to 50 again.

here is my code

```
foreach($order->productId->inventory as $currentRequestedCount){
     $currentRequested = $order->quantity * $order->relatedPackage ->unit_count;
        if($currentRequestedCount->type == "existing"){
            $currentRequested -= $currentRequestedCount->amount;
        }
}
```

how to prevent the `$currentRequestedCount` from being reset?

Comment: use a product id to keep separate count for each product's inventory level, e.g.: `$currentRequested[$productId]`

Comment: @berend can you show example please.

Comment: Do you mean being able to update `$currentRequestedCount`, have you tried using a reference in the foreach `as &$currentRequestedCount){` (adding the `&`)

Comment: @NigelRen yes I try as `&$currentRequestedCount` this but no different. I need to make this `currentRequestedCount` each time I decrease to be as it's but in this case each time it loops it overwrite and rest to 50 again.

Comment: Better to use 2 tables: inventory and order.

Comment: @jspit I have two tables.

Answer (score 1):

I use arrays to illustrate this. You have your inventory:

```
$inventory = [
  //product => inventory
  1 => 50,
  7 => 150,
];
```

You get a few orders:

```
$order = [
  ['product' => 1, 'quantity' => 5],
  ['product' => 1, 'quantity' => 6],
  ['product' => 7, 'quantity' => 2],
  ['product' => 1, 'quantity' => 6],
];
```

The orders are processed (without handling errors!).

```
foreach($order as $row){
  $inventory[$row['product']] -= $row['quantity'];
}
```

The current inventory:

```
var_dump($inventory);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  int(33)
  [7]=>
  int(148)
}
```